# At what rate do Zerg units regenerate HP in Brood War?

Tags: starcraft-zerg, starcraft

I remember they regenerate at a uniform rate over time, but what is that rate in HP/s?

Do all units regenerate at the same rate? Do units and building regenerate at the same rate?

Comment: Offhand I think it's .5 per second but I also can't test. =p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Zerg units and buildings regenerate at the flat rate of approximately

- **0.372 hp/s** or
- **1 hp per 2.685 sec**

In comparison to SC2, the **hp regen rate is the same**, regardless of whether the unit is on plain terrain, on creep or burrowed.

---

### The Setup

[image: plagued hydras]

1. I made a custom game in Brood War 1.16.1 *(bonus points if you can name the map by the screenshots)*.
2. The game speed was set to Fastest. In Fastest game speed, one real second is 1.4 game seconds. (But since there's no in-built clock, it doesn't really matter.)
3. I placed 1 hydra on plain terrain, 1 hydra on creep, and I burrowed 1 hydra.
4. I used a [Defiler's Plague](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Plague) to bring 3 hydras down to 1 hp each. This was the easiest way because Plague ignores armor and deals damage by synchronous time ticks. So all the hydras were taking the same damage at the same milli/microsecond.
5. Once plague wore off, I used a stopwatch to time how long it took to regen 10 hp.
6. I took 10 samples of each case. Then I averaged and rounded the results.

[image: 3 hydra health]

I also cycled through and screenshot the health of each hydra between the ticks of hp regen. All 3 hydras have 63 hp in the screenshot.

### The Results

- Hydralisk on creep - 10 hp / 26.85 s
- Hydralisk off creep - 10 hp / 26.85 s
- Burrowed Hydralisk - 10 hp / 26.85 s
- Larva - 10 hp / 26.85 s
- Hatchery - 10 hp 26.85 s

---

### Exception: Eggs

Since units spawn relatively quickly compared to the duration of Plague, instead of waiting for Plague's damage, I blasted an egg down from 200 hp to ~100 hp and waited.

**(!)** Zerg eggs **do not** regen hp at all.

- Egg - 0 hp / 30 seconds

But they have 10 armor, so they're hard to take down to begin with.

---

And for fun, I plagued a Kakaru =P

[image: Kakaru]

It also has no regen ☃

Comment: I'd appreciate edits that reorganize the information to improve clarity =)

Comment: Blue Storm... =)

Comment: Also, the conversion from Fastest to normal in SC:BW is just slightly over 1.4:1.

Comment: @Decency Haha I knew you would know it. Thanks for the time ratio! Do you know a source I can link to in the answer?

Comment: No source, just a thousand Sniper Paintball games that take 30 minutes of game time but 21:12 real time.

Comment: @Decency hahaha

Comment: 0.372/s = 1/64 per frame (A frame has 42ms on fastest). The power-of-two fraction fits SC's use of binary fixedpoint numbers.

Comment: Ok, this is a great answer :).

Comment: You ask and answer yourself?

Comment: @Ooker I finally answered it when nobody else did